# How to visit multiple dataframe one by one in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 4 dataframes say A, B, C, D that have same columns.

I want to do something like:

`for x in (A,B,C,D):
   do something`

It means I want to perform the same task on each dataframe one by one. I tried:

`for (x in c(A,B,C,D)) {
  do something
}`

but it does not work.

How could I do that in R?

Thank you very much

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) for a number of options. Gregor's answer there gives you some tips for working with such objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make list of them, say:

```
X <- list (A, B, C, D)
```

and then use `lapply` or `sapply`:

```
lapply(X, function_doing_something)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of dataframes

```
x <- list(A, B, C, D)
for(i in 1:length(x)) {
your function here }
```

You'll be supposed to access each dataframe in the list as `x[[i]]`

Hope this helps!